# Learning AJAX with Wordpress and can't figure out how to debug my mistake

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm new to wordpress and I'm having trouble getting an AJAX call to work in a plugin. Nothing I try to print to console on the frontend shows up while I have an ajax request running and I don't know how to make anything print to anywhere from the wordpress backend.

If possible, I'd appreciate if someone could tell me how to debug my mistake.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $('#question-form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        console.log(this);
        //var formData = new FormData(this);
        var formData = {
            action: 'create_question',
            post_content: jQuery('#question-form #question-content').val()
        };
        $.ajax({
          type: 'post',
          dataType: 'json',
          url: '<?php echo wp_localize_script(admin_url( "admin-ajax.php" )); ?>',
          data: formData,
          processData: false,
          contentType: false,
          success: function(response) {
            if(response.type == "success") {
                console.log("test");
               // Update question display
            }
            else {
               alert("Error");
            }
          },
          error: function(xhr, textStatus, error) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
            console.log(xhr.statusText);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(error);
          }
        });
      });
    });
        
</script>

<?php
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_create_question', 'create_question_handler' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_create_question', 'create_question_handler' );

    function create_question_handler() {
        wp_send_json(123);
    }
?>
```

When I delete the ajax, it logs the formdata to console. Otherwise, nothing logs to console except for a navigation to a new blank page. I was under the impression that AJAX is used to avoid loading a new page, so this also confuses me.

I don't know how to confirm whether my hooks are being created or where to look to see if my handler is outputting anything.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: You should start by checking whether this is a JS problem or a PHP problem. Afterwards, use one of the many tutorials available for debugging (either in the browser, through it's developer console, or in your IDE through something like XDebug)

Comment: You should double check the documentation of the [wp_localize_script()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/) function to learn what it's actually for, that's at least one of the problems with your code as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

your `url` parameter is using an unnecessary function. it should be:

```
url: '<?php echo esc_url( admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php') ); ?>',
```